Type guard with generic extending enum
I want to have a type guard with a generic type extending an enum. Here's my example:
enum Fruit {
    Apple = "apple",
    Banana = "banana",
}

function exemple<T extends Fruit>(fruit: T, fruitSalad: T[]) {
    if (isApple(fruit)) {
        // Here I want fruitSalad to be typed as Apple[] implicitely
        console.log(fruitSalad);
    }
}

I know we can do:
function isApple(fruit: Fruit): fruit is Fruit.Apple {
    return fruit === Fruit.Apple;
}

but this doesn't work in my case for fruitSalad, only for fruit.
I tried:
function isApple2<T extends Fruit>(fruit: T): fruit is Fruit.Apple {
    return fruit === Fruit.Apple;
}

But I have the error
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
   Type 'Fruit.Apple' is not assignable to type 'T'.
     'Fruit.Apple' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Fruit'.ts(2677)

and I don't know how to manage it
I also saw Generic enum type guard but I didn't manage to adapt it to my problem.

You have to check fruitSalad as well.
Something like this will work
enum Fruit {
    Apple = "apple",
    Banana = "banana",
}

function exemple<T extends Fruit>(fruit: T, fruitSalad: T[]) {
  if (isApple(fruit) && isAppleSalad(fruitSalad)) {
    // Here I want fruitSalad to be typed as Apple[] implicitely
    console.log(fruitSalad); //: Fruit.Apple[]
    console.log(fruit); //: Fruit.Apple
  }
}

function isApple(fruit: Fruit): fruit is Fruit.Apple {
  return fruit === Fruit.Apple;
}
function isAppleSalad(fruitSalad: Fruit[]): fruitSalad is Fruit.Apple[] {
  return fruitSalad.every(isApple);
}


So by checking if it is apple salad then TS will know. playground

Shouldn't you check fruitSalad.every(isApple)? Checking only the first fruit (if any) is not sufficient.

yes, i just did the dirtiest way possible because the point is to check not how to check. I'll update it


I want fruitSalad to be typed as Apple[] implicitely, but this doesn't work in my case for fruitSalad, only for fruit.

Because it would be wrong. isApple(fruit) only checks the runtime type of fruit, it says nothing about fruitSalad. Notice that it does not constrain the type of T.
The type signature function example<T extends Fruit>(fruit: T, fruitSalad: T[]) allows calling
example<Fruit>(Fruit.Apple, [Fruit.Banana]);

Maybe you meant to use an overload instead of a generic:
function example(apple: Apple, appleSalad: Apple[]): void;
function example(banana: Banana, bananaSalad: Banana[]): void;
function example(fruit: Fruit, someSalad: Fruit[]): void {
    …
}

but that seems boring (and unsavoury), and still wouldn't solve your type inference issue in the implementation.

My approach would generally look like this but yeah
